# Импорт данных с HTML-страницы для работы кода на Python

Tags: python, html, flask, pyscript

Мне нужно вставить код Python так, чтобы он считывал две переменные из окон ввода данных в HTML, а также два файла Excel, запускал код при нажатии кнопки и выводил результат работы программы в специальный div.
Как это можно сделать?
Я попробовал использовать два фреймворка Flask и Py Script. Не получается сделать так, чтобы код Python извлекал данные и таблицы Excel из окон ввода и выводил результат на html-страницу.

df и df1 должно считывать из HTML страницы из окошек id="file-input-1" и id="file-input-2" соответственно. your_choice из id="pipeline-input", а your_choice_year из id="data-input". при нажатии на кнопку id="runCodeButton" должен срабатывать код питон и выводить результат result на страницу

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/calculate', methods=['POST'])
def calculate():
    df = pd.read_excel(request.files['file-input-1'], index_col=0)
    df1 = pd.read_excel(request.files['file-input-2'], index_col=0)
    your_choice = request.form['pipeline-input']
    your_choice_year = int(request.form['data-input'])

    name_list = df.index.tolist()

    def f(your_choice, df, df1, name_list, your_choice_year):
...........
    return render_template('index.html', result=result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```